# Why do I continuously get errors when trying to use quiver using data from a NetCDF file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mapping, netcdf

I have been trying different methods found online, and even made a ton of alters but I cannot get quiver to work correctly. This is leading to lots of different errors that I am having a hard time solving. I used the following data: https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/NARR/monolevel/ and downloaded uwnd.10m.2016.nc and vwnd.10m.2016.nc to create the quivers.

Here is one of the methods I tried and the image I get is attached:

```
uwnd = xr.open_dataset('uwnd.10m.2015.nc').sel(time='2016-09-18')
vwnd = xr.open_dataset('vwnd.10m.2015.nc').sel(time='2016-09-18')
X = uwnd.x; Y = uwnd.y
U = uwnd.uwnd; V = vwnd, vwnd

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.quiver(X[::3],Y[::3],U[::3],V[::3], color='green')
ax.set_extent([-125, -70, 20,55])


ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=1)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)

plt.show()
```

[Quiver Map after adding code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj4lM.png)